# Promise.all is not displaying the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am new to promises and I want to return the data from classes as promises. I have two classes with two function in each class. What I am doing each function is returning a promise from a class, but I am unable to execute promise.all. Below is the code

```
Class1

class TestClass {

    firstPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('return first promise')
        })
    }

    secondPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('return second promise')
        })
    }
}
module.exports.TestClass = TestClass;

Class2

class TestClass1 {

    firstPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('return first promise')
        })
    }

    secondPromise() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve('return second promise')
        })
    }
}
module.exports.TestClass1 = TestClass1;

Main function
    let data = req.body;
    let test1Object;
    let testObject;
    let testParam;
    let testParam1;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('param1')) {
        test1Object = new test1.TestClass1();
        test1Object.firstPromise().then((data)=>{
            testParam1 = test1Object.secondPromise();
        });
    }
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('param2')) {
        testObject = new test.TestClass();
        testObject.firstPromise().then((data)=>{
            testParam = testObject.secondPromise()
        });
    }
    Promise.all([testParam,testParam1]).then((data)=>{
       console.log(data)
    });
```

it displays
[ undefined, undefined ]

Comment: `Promise.all` takes an array of promises, not an array of "variables" that will be filled with a value in the future by some promise callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're executing `Promise.all()`, the promises are not yet resolved, so `testParam` and `testParam1` are `undefined`. I think you should assign the first promise to `testParam1`:

```
testParam1 = test1Object.firstPromise().then(data => test1Object.secondPromise());
```

and similarly the second to `testParam`:

```
testParam = testObject.firstPromise().then(data => testObject.secondPromise());
```